# package npm project written in flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, flowtype

I have to publish a **npm package** that is written with **Flow** and compiled using **babel**.

What I did was I compiled all my source files. Then I copied compiled files from **dist/** and put them into some other directory. I also put **package.json** there and edited it and then I published the package on npm.

I can then normally install project and require it my project. However when I run my project, it throws error that I need to require `babel-core` and `babel-polyfills` (install them as dev-dependencies). The problem is since my new project only requires my own package and does not use babel or something like that, so I see no point in requiring babel dependencies in my new project.

My question is, how can I package my library that is written with Flow and compiled by babel, so that I can then use this package in other places without requiring babel.

Comment: they're polyfills for older browsers

Comment: this is package used by node.js so there is no need for browser compatibility and I don't want to force users of my package to require babel in their projects, just because they use my library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in using incorrectly defined preset
In my babelrc I only had defined
`preset: "env"` without specifying that it needs to run on node 8 and higher, since the code used async.
Therefore i defined preset as:

```
preset: ["env", {
    targets: {
        "node": "8.9.1"
    }
}
```

And the asnyc functions compiles correctly.

Also, thanks to @Kenneth I used flow-copy-source to add type to my library, so it can be seen in intelisense.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add **main** and **files** into your package.json?

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files

Your files should probably be

```
"files": [
  "dist/**"
],
```

Also to prevent Users who install your package from needing to install the transpilers (i.e **babel**) add them into your **devDependencies**

Directly from the https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

> Please do not put test harnesses or **transpilers** in your dependencies object. See **devDependencies**, below.

Also to add flow to your dist add https://github.com/AgentME/flow-copy-source

`flow-copy-source -v src dist`

Comment: yes I did. the package works - it is installed from npm and I can use it in my project, the only problem is because alongside i need to install those two babel dependencies and I want to package my library without needing from user to install those dependencies

Comment: You can move the babel dependencies to  "devDependencies" so the user doesn't need to install them

Comment: but if I do that, then when user downloads my library it will fail due to lacking babel dependencies. somehow the compiled version is still reliant on babel, but i want to get rid of that.

Comment: How are you building your `dist`?

Comment: babel src -d dist
with this in my .babelrc: `{ "presets": [ "env", "stage-0", "flow" ], "plugins": [ ["module-resolver", { "root": ["./src/"], }], "transform-class-properties", "transform-flow-strip-types" ] }`

Comment: Try `rm -rf dist && babel src -d dist && flow-copy-source -v src dist` making sure you have the` flow-copy-source` in devDependencies https://github.com/AgentME/flow-copy-source

Comment: this doesnt solve the problem. i get .flow files but the library is still not working. I read somewhere that i need to require babel-polyfills in my main source file, however since this is a compiled version i do not think this is what i should do. (even though it works that way). the compiled version should work with complete absence of babel, right?

Comment: You do need to add `babel-polyfill` or at least a `polyfill` for the features that you used.